# expand (pull down) iPhone statusbar programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

Is there a way to expand/collapse statusbar programmatically?
This is just for my experimental app. I do not intend to place it on the market.

Thanks

Edit: I mean expanding it as when a user touches and pulls it down.

In Android, I have seen it's doable: [How to open or expand status bar through intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021310/how-to-open-or-expand-status-bar-through-intent) and [Preventing status bar expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457730/preventing-status-bar-expansion).
So, I like to know if it's possible on iOS.

(I prefer it works on non-jailbreak phones but any idea from jailbreak guys is very welcome.)

Comment: You might get a better response if you edit the question to be a bit more clear. What you really want to do is pull down the notification sheet, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I added more details.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this question:

[GSSendEvent - Inject Touch Event iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160589/gssendevent-inject-touch-event-ios)

Answer in there explains how to inject touch events.

You can inject several touch events to open a status bar.

Comment: I have seen that answer. It seems like GSEvent doesn't work in the statusbar area. I can send the touch but not in the statusbar area.

Comment: What port do you send events to?

Comment: I use the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156831/how-to-find-the-purple-port-for-the-front-most-application-in-ios-5-and-above/16157532#16157532

Comment: @EntryLevelDev: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to recommend to user2324713 to try.

Comment: I tried GSGetPurpleSystemEventPort...no error but nothing happens. :(