# How can I programmatically expand status bar on samsung lollipop devices?

Tags: android, statusbar

I use this code to expand status bar:

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
Method showsb;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
} 
else { 
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
} 
showsb.invoke( sbservice );
```

With permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

It work well exept with the samsung lollipop device nothing happen.
Does anyone know how to expand status bar on samsung lollipop device?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you answer this question based on accessibility service https://stackoverflow.com/q/49734263/4813904

Comment: On which device didn't it work? I've used about the same code too:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51616031/878126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found it but I need to use the Accessibility service:

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    Log.e("MyAccessibilityService", "get event");
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case 1:
                Log.e("MyAccessibilityService ", "home");
                performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_HOME);
                break;
            case 2:
                Log.e("MyAccessibilityService ", "back");
                performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
                break;
            case 3:
                Log.e("MyAccessibilityService ", "power");
                performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG);
                break;
            case 4:
                Log.e("MyAccessibilityService ", "noti");
                performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS);
                break;

        }


    }
}
```

Fire even:

```
AccessibilityEvent event1 = AccessibilityEvent.obtain(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END);
        event1.setClassName(className);
        event1.getText().add("noti");
        event1.setAction(4);
        event1.setPackageName(packageName);
        event1.setEnabled(true);
        AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
        AccessibilityRecordCompat recordCompat = AccessibilityEventCompat.asRecord(event1);
        recordCompat.setSource(v);
        if (Utility.isAccessibilityEnable(context)) {
            manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event1);
        }
```

Comment: Does it works on latest Android version and all other devices??

Comment: @SivaKReddyCShiva I think it still does. The Accessibility service does not change much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Is it possible to take screenshots after expanding the status bar